# Grails ORM to point data type in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, types, grails-orm

I'm using GORM to map to the PostgreSQL database.
I'm trying to map the locationxy which is lat / long to point data type in PostgreSQL.

```
static mapping = {

 locationXY type: 'point'

}
```

But I get an error of unknown data type:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type
>   for: Point, at table: locations, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(locationxy)]

Comment: I wouldn't know about GORM, but one thing stick out: in the error message `Point` is capitalized. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the Hibernate spacial plugin.  Since Hibernate types can be used from Grails I think that's the place to start.  http://www.grails.org/plugin/hibernate-spatial-postgresql